# Mongoose save method saves multiple times same document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hi I have one input field date selector on angular UI. I select the date from field and update the starting Date and till there it works correctly. but If I select the date again it duplicates the document instead of updating it.

working code:

```
router.post('/request/waiting/:startingDate', (req, res) => {
  const waiting = new WaitingRequest({
    startingDate: req.params.startingDate,
    requestID: req.body.requestID,
    contactInformation: req.body.contactInformation,
    orderInformation: req.body.orderInformation,
    requestInformation: req.body.requestInformation,
    installations: req.body.installations
  });
  waiting.save().then(result => {
    return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Updated and Saved /waiting',
      result: result
    });
  });
});
```

what I have tried so far but it returns null:

```
router.post('/request/waiting/:startingDate', (req, res) => {
  WaitingRequest.findOneAndUpdate({
    requestID: req.body.requestID
  }, {
    startingDate: req.params.startingDate
  }).then(result => {
    console.log(result)
    if (result) {
      return res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Updated and saved',
        result: result
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: "404 Request Not Found"
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Your question is bit confusing? Is `startingDate` is unique field?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UpdateOne()` mongoose method to update your data,

```
router.post('/request/waiting/:startingDate', (req, res) => {
    let query = { requestID: req.body.requestID }
    let update = { $set: { startingDate: new Date(req.params.startingDate) } }
    WaitingRequest.updateOne(query, update,(error,result)=>{
        if(error) return res.status(404).json({ message: "404 Request Not Found" })
        return res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Updated and saved',
            result: result
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: `{
    "message": "Updated and saved",
    "result": {
        "n": 0,
        "nModified": 0,
        "ok": 1
    }
}`

Comment: but it did not create any document or updated anything but sent message 201 created but nothing is there

Comment: what format for `req.params.startingDate` is there ?

Comment: same thing happened but it did not create document!

Comment: please add your schema and some duplicate content, try console.log `new Date(req.params.startingDate)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194940/discussion-between-nikhil-savaliya-and-muhammad-ali).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the $set clause in the findOneAndUpdate

EDIT: Improving the code to use promise and sending a Date object as for starting date

Try this:

```
router.post('/request/waiting/:startingDate', (req, res) => {


WaitingRequest.findOneAndUpdate({
    requestID: req.body.requestID
  }, { $set: {
    startingDate: new Date(req.params.startingDate)
    }
  }).then(result => {
      return res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Updated and saved',
        result: result
      })
  }).catch(error => {
      res.send({ error })
   })
});
```

Comment: should work this way! if not, show me what the error is

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting a 404 error is findOneAndUpdate was unable to find the required document based on requestID. The only missing piece to the puzzle is

> `new` : bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the
>   original. defaults to false (changed in 4.0)

```
router.post('/request/waiting/:startingDate', (req, res) => {

  WaitingRequest.findOneAndUpdate({
    requestID: req.body.requestID
    }, { $set: {
       startingDate: new Date(req.params.startingDate)
    }, {
       upsert:true, new: true,
    },
  }).then(result => {
       return res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Updated and saved',
        result: result
      })
  }).catch(error => {
       res.send({ error })
   })
});
```

[Reference: mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

Hope this answers your question.